# Confused about the CAAction's run method

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to understand how this method [run(forKey:object:arguments:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caaction/1410806-run) is operating exactly in the following code from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayerdelegate/2097264-action):

```swift
let delegate = LayerDelegate()
     
lazy var sublayer: CALayer = {
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.delegate = self.delegate
    
    return layer
}()
     
func moveSublayer() {
    guard let action = sublayer.action(forKey: "moveRight") else {
        return
    }
    
    action.run(forKey: "transform", object: sublayer, arguments: nil) // this line
}
     
class LayerDelegate: NSObject, CALayerDelegate {
    func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        
        guard event == "moveRight" else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let animation = CABasicAnimation()
        animation.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: CAValueFunctionName.translateX)
        animation.fromValue = 1
        animation.toValue = 300
        animation.duration = 2
        
        return animation
    }
}
```

I'm particularly confused about the `forKey` parameter from `action.run(forKey: "transform", object: sublayer, arguments: nil)`.

In the documentation, it's stated as:

> The identifier of the action. The identifier may be a key or key path
> relative to anObject, an arbitrary external action, or one of the
> action identifiers defined in CALayer.

I understand that the animation list in the render tree is like a dictionary so you query the list with a key and you get a particular animation as a value, which is what happened in the example above. The sublayer queries the animation list with "moveRight":

```swift
guard let action = sublayer.action(forKey: "moveRight") else {
    return
}
```

And then the action is returned with the following method:

```swift
func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
    guard event == "moveRight" else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let animation = CABasicAnimation()
    animation.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: kCAValueFunctionTranslateX)
    animation.fromValue = 1
    animation.toValue = 300
    animation.duration = 2
    
    return animation
}
```

But, what is this forKey: "transform" for? We've already queried the animation list with the "moveRight" key and got the value. Why do we need another key?

Also, what if I were to create a group animation combining transform and opacity or other non-transform property? What would I have to use instead of forKey: "transform"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All CALayer properties are accessible by their string names via key-value coding. That fact is the basis of implicit layer animation and the entire CAAction mechanism.

Okay, well, there is no `moveRight` property. `"moveRight"` is just a name we made up. You have to ask yourself *how* we are going to move right.

In this example, we are going to do it by animating the layer's `transform`, in particular using a translate transform with an X component that goes from 1 to 300 (as you see in the `action(forLayer)` implementation). Hence we must use the `"transform"` key, because we want to animate the `transform` property.

Comment: But, isn't "how" already specified with `CAValueFunction(name: CAValueFunctionName.translateX)`?

Comment: That supplements / modifies the way you express the transform animation, but you still need to say it _is_ a transform animation. For another example of using a value function look at case 8 in this code from my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/ddd2b9f22660b61a2878cf60812a814ecc8b85b1/bk2ch04p148layerAnimation/ch17p490layerAnimation/ViewController.swift